# What is multiset multicover problem in set-theory with an example?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Can you provide with an example on multiset multicover problem. I am not able to find any good examples however I understand what is cover of a set. But what are multi-cover and multi set?
update:
It would be great if you give an example for this set below:  $${s= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6\}}$$

Answer (score -1):

Given a universe N containing n elements and a collection of multisets or sets over N, the multiset multicover or the set multicover problem is to cover all elements at least a number of times as specified in their coverage requirements with the minimum number of multisets or sets. In this paper, we give various exact algorithms for these two problems, with or without constraints on the number of times a multiset or set may be picked.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, can you please explain with an example.

Comment: "In this paper..." -- in what paper?